# Just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10. Bluetooth not working

Tags: upgrade, updates, bluetooth, update-manager, 23.10

Even after turning my device on for Pairing Mode, no device would show up in Bluetooth section to be able to connect. I mean there actually are no devices found.
I updated and upgraded everything in Terminal and Software Updater and Software Center, but issue isn't resolved yet.

Please someone help if they can as I'm reluctant to reinstall!